# unable to run basic Py program in Pycharm with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I'm very new to coding. Trying to run the below basic lines from past 20 days,  and getting the below error. Kindly help. Tried installing uninstalling python, selenium & pycharm. still same issue :(

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application')
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
browser.quit()
```

Error -

```
"C:\Python 3.7.6\python.exe" C:/Users/PycharmProjects/sel/sel1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 3.7.6\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python 3.7.6\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python 3.7.6\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/sel/sel1.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application')
  File "C:\Python 3.7.6\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python 3.7.6\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Application' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So i need to download chromedriver and then provide the path in exec path, right??

Comment: Backslashes are escape chars in Python.   So your path is not what you are expecting.  Use double backslashes or forward slashes in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Your executable path is deeply problematic. The error being thrown show that your programs access to the chrome driver is being blocked. Change the position of the chrome driver to somewhere else(desktop, user directory etc) and change the executable path in your code to the new path where you put your chromedriver and you should be okay

Comment: I hope you have downloaded chromedriver and you are not trying to use selenium with your normal chrome browser

Comment: Correct Sir, im using normal Chrome browser path. So i understand that I need to download chromedriver and then provide that path in exec path right??

Comment: The executable path is the path to the chrome driver. So yes and yes